# Field Integrity Exception

Tags: triggers, apex

Field Integrity Exception in the Trigger

```
class="{!(empty(v.simpleRecord.SR_Id__c) &amp;&amp; (v.simpleRecord.Service_Site__c != null &amp;&amp; v.simpleRecord.Site_Contact__c != null) &amp;&amp; not(empty(v.simpleRecord.Account.Siebel_Row_Id__c)) &amp;&amp; not(empty(v.simpleRecord.AccountId)) &amp;&amp; not(empty(v.simpleRecord.ZEB_Serial_Number__c)) &amp;&amp; not(empty(v.simpleRecord.ZEB_Product_Name__c)) &amp;&amp; empty(v.simpleRecord.SR_Number__c) &amp;&amp; (v.simpleRecord.Entitlement_Status__c=='NOT ENTITLED') &amp;&amp; (v.simpleRecord.Status != 'Solution Provided' &amp;&amp; v.simpleRecord.Status != 'Customer No Response' &amp;&amp; v.simpleRecord.Status != 'Mis-Routed' &amp;&amp; v.simpleRecord.Status != 'Customer Solved' &amp;&amp; v.simpleRecord.Status != 'Closed') &amp;&amp; (v.createServiceRequest== true) &amp;&amp; not(empty(v.simpleRecord.Type)) &amp;&amp; !v.disableSRCreation &amp;&amp; not(v.simpleRecord.Entitlement_Status__c == 'CONTRACT' &amp;&amp; (v.simpleRecord.ZEBOfferingType__c == 'On Site China' &amp;&amp; v.simpleRecord.Type == 'Field Service' &amp;&amp; v.simpleRecord.Service_Site_Country__c == 'China' &amp;&amp; (v.simpleRecord.Case_Account_Organization__c == 'Zebra APAC RMB'|| v.simpleRecord.Case_Account_Organization__c == 'Zebra APAC USD'))?'slds-show':'slds-hide'}">
                        <lightning:select name="vendorNameChina"
```

That is the class I have written, but getting a Field Integrity Exception.